# Service methods not working in android

Tags: android, android-service, toast

I just created a service as shown below :

```
package com.example.timepass;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class alarm extends Service{


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Entered in service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

         Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return 1; 

        // Log.i("YourService", "Yes this works.");
     }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
}



}
```

Now when I startservice from mainactivity by the following command:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.timepass.ALARM");
MainActivity.this.startService(myIntent);
```

By doing this there is no error, but no TOAST of Service class are dipslayed

My manifest is :

```
<service class=".alarm" android:name=".alarm" android:enabled="true">
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:value="com.example.timepass.ALARM"
               android:name=".alarm" />

       </intent-filter>
   </service>
```

Please guide me!!!

Comment: check your service is running or not from application manager

Comment: @prosper ofcourse it would not be running as it does not display any toast!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have the `service in your manifest`, or it does not have an  that matches your action. Examining LogCat should turn up some warnings that may help.

More likely, you should start the service via:

```
startService(new Intent(this, alarm.class));
```

Comment: your manifest is ok, start your service by this way startService(new Intent(this, alarm.class));